# How to get selected controls from GridView with SelectionMode=Multiple

Tags: c#, gridview, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile, visual-studio-2015

I have a GridView like this:

```
<GridView x:Name="list" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" SelectionChanged="list_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Wallpapers}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:ImageItem">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource ImageMenuFlyout}" Width="150" Height="90" Source="{x:Bind img}" Tag="{x:Bind TagIndex}" Holding="Image_Holding" Tapped="Image_Tapped"/>
                <Image Source="used.png" Height="15" Margin="0,-15,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="44" Visibility="{x:Bind Used, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

I need to get on the OnSelectionChanged method of the GrifView the visibility of the second Image control.

I need this because if the user select at least one item which have the second Image control visibility to "Visible", I have to enable a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried to recreate your example.

I assume you have a class called `ImageItem`. I created one with only the `Used` property:

```
public class ImageItem
{
    public Visibility Used { get; set; }
}
```

My view is basically the same as yours, I used different `ItemsSource` name and only left in the `Visibility` binding of the second `Image` control:

```
<GridView x:Name="list" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" SelectionChanged="List_OnSelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ImageItem">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Width="150" Height="90" />
                <Image Height="15" Margin="0,-15,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="44" Visibility="{x:Bind Used, Mode=OneWay}"  />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

I bound it to the following collection:

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<ImageItem>
{
    new ImageItem() { Used = Visibility.Visible },
    new ImageItem() { Used = Visibility.Visible },
    new ImageItem() { Used = Visibility.Collapsed },
};
```

So only the third item's second `Image` is hidden.

My selection changed handler is the following:

```
private void List_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var gridView = sender as GridView;

    if (gridView != null)
    {
        var isAtLeastOneVisible =
            gridView.SelectedItems.OfType<ImageItem>().Any(i => i.Used == Visibility.Visible);
    }
}
```

So `isAtLeastOneVisible` will be true if you select at least the first and/or the second item in the list, and will be false if you only select the third item.

Comment: Thank you very much, you understand perfectly what I mean. It works properly. Where I can find a guide to that code (i => i.Used == Visibility.Visible), I don't understand it very well. Thanks.

Comment: It is called a lambda expression, they are very useful. MSDN link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx
Another simple explanation: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/298963/Understand-Lambda-Expressions-in-Minutes

Comment: It works like a foreach cicle or this lambda expresion is better in terms of speed?